# WPF : Remove context menu items based on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a context menu in WPF with following items:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.MyContext_Command1}" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.MyContext_Command2}" Command="{Binding Command2}" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.MyContext_Command3}" Command="{Binding Command3}" Visibility="{Binding IsItemActive, Converter={converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.MyContext_Command4}" Command="{Binding Command4}" Visibility="{Binding IsItemActive, Converter={converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Separator Visibility="{Binding IsItemActive, Converter={converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

With the above code these menu items(Command3 and Command4) are appearing grey(Disabled) when IsItemActive = false and appear black(Enabled) when IsItemActive = true. But i want my Menuitems(Command3 and Command4) and also Seperator to Disappear / Appear from context menu based on "IsItemActive".How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Easiest way is to bind a collection to your ContextMenu. And in your ViewModel you control the object that is bound. You add/remove items from the observable collection and your ContextMenu appears as you expected. This is the simplest way and best way to handle.

Comment: It seems to you are trying to define Visibility based on IsItemActive property which belong to some item in ItemsControl (GridView or ListBox).
In such case keep attention to DataContext for MenuItem. Probably you need to use RelativeSource or ElementName for change source for binding in Visibility property.

Comment: We need to see more code. For example, what happens if you would set those to `Visibility="Collapsed"` manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. But I cannot get my bindings to work now so it's not tested. You will have to give a name to the element that you are applying this in order to make the binding work. For my case, it's a window.

Create a *[dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0)* for `IsItemActive` only then you can bind.
Tip : type `propdp` and double tab in Visual Studio to use code snippet.

```
<Window x:Class.....
    x:Name="mainwindow" 
...>
```

Then in the `<Window.Resources>` define the styles

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=mainwindow,Path=IsItemActive}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=mainwindow,Path=IsItemActive}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Duplicate the style and change `TargetType="Separator"` Then apply the style on your context menu items and separator.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.MyContext_Command1}" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.MyContext_Command2}" Command="{Binding Command2}" />
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.MyContext_Command3}" Command="{Binding Command3}" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" />
    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.MyContext_Command4}" Command="{Binding Command4}" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" />
    <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```